# How to take screen shot programmatically (Swift, SpriteKit)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uigraphicscontext, skview

I tried what ever was suggested but the output was a white,blank screenshot. Which leads me to assume that I haven't added anything to the view. Here's how I'm adding graphics to my view. The addChild method comes with the SpriteKit and it takes in SKSpriteNodes:

```
  addChild(background)
    addChild(rate)
    addChild(scoreLabel)
    addChild(share)
    addChild(playAgain)
    addChild(highScoreLabel)
    addChild(scoreBackground)
    addChild(highScoreBackground)
```

Here's the method that takes the screenshot:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view!.bounds.size)
    self.view!.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

Any suggestions would be helpful

Comment: the addChild method comes with the SpriteKit framework. I'm not sure what it's adding them to. But I use it to make the sprites visible. However when I use the screenshot method it returns a white , blank screenshot.

Comment: You have to call addChild on some SKNode. With the code you've posted it's not clear what view or node you're adding them to (if any)

Comment: Marking me down for what? I lost two points for what? This is ridiculous and you guys should be ashamed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think this question could be merged with this one
[Screenshotting on Iphone in swift only has a white background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25702775/1139044)

which seems the same

EDIT:

I think I found a solution.
First read this post: [How Do I Take a Screen Shot of a UIView?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18925301/1139044)

I create an Extensions.swift file in which I 'extended' the methods of a UIView using that link.

After that I simply connect the following to my sprite-kit button

```
let screenshot = self.view?.pb_takeSnapshot()
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot, nil, nil, nil)
```

Voilà, the image is in the camera roll!

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I solved it in swift 3: This captures all the nodes in your scene:
Note:  in below code represents the view it is capturing from. You may want to update it with your view in project.

```
func captureScreen() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(yourview.bounds.size, true, 0)

    yourview.drawHierarchy(in: yourview.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)


    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return image
}
```